# Por que VBA getElementByClassName no funciona en una computadora pero si en otra, con identicas librerias referenciadas

Tags: excel, web, vba

tengo un script que hace scrapping en una pagina y funciona perfectamente desde una notebook con WIN11, IE11 y Framework, pero en otra notebook identica funciona parcialmente, las setencias getElementByTagName traen los datos correctamente pero no funciona getElementByClassName.
Alguna idea de como solucionarlo? aqui parte del codigo

```
    Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.serverXMLHTTP")
    
    XMLPage.Open "Get", url, False
    XMLPage.send
    htmldoc.body.innerHTML = XMLPage.responseText 'chapo
    
    Set htmlims = htmldoc.getElementsByClassName("andes-pagination__page-count")
    
    If htmldoc.querySelectorAll(".andes-pagination__page-count").Length = 0 Then
        PageIndex = 1
    Else
        PageIndex = Replace(htmldoc.querySelectorAll(".andes-pagination__page-count").item(0).innerText, "de ", "")
    End If
    
    If PageIndex = 0 Then PageIndex = CInt(PageIndex)
    
    On Error Resume Next
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(solapa)
     Lastrow = (.Range("A" & .Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row) + 1
    End With
    
     fila = Lastrow
     i = 0
     Set htmlims = htmldoc.getElementsByClassName("ui-search-result__wrapper")
        For Each htmlim In htmlims
         Sheets(solapa).Cells(fila, 2).Value = Replace(htmlim.getElementsByTagName("a")(0).getAttribute("title"), vbLf, "")
         Sheets(solapa).Cells(fila, 4).Value = CDbl(htmlim.getElementsByClassName("price-tag__disabled").item(0).getElementsByClassName("price-tag-fraction").item(0).outerText)
         Sheets(solapa).Cells(fila, 3).Value = CDbl(htmlim.getElementsByClassName("ui-search-price__second-line").item(0).getElementsByClassName("price-tag-fraction").item(0).outerText) 'CDbl(htmldoc.querySelectorAll(".price-tag-fraction").item(i).outerText) '
         Sheets(solapa).Cells(fila, 1).Value = Categoria
         Sheets(solapa).Cells(fila, 5).Value = solapa
         Sheets(solapa).Cells(fila, 6).Value = htmlim.getElementsByTagName("a")(0).getAttribute("href")
         ThisWorkbook.Sheets(solapa).Hyperlinks.Add Range("C" & fila), Address:=Sheets(solapa).Cells(fila, 6).Value
        fila = fila + 1
        i = i + 1
     Next htmlim
```

El script funciona perfecto en una pc pero no en otra

la pagina que analiza es https://tienda.mercadolibre.com.ar/drinks-co

Gracias!!

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: "un script", "no funciona" son malas descripciones para un problema. Añade los detalles, el script, el error que sale cuando no funciona como esperas, revisa la consola del navegador. Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante
(en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).
La opción editar está justo bajo la pregunta y las etiquetas!

Comment: IE9+ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName